# How to mirror storage array over a WAN

Tags: replication, sas, mirroring

We are looking at adding a SAS storage array to a server and would like to mirror the array (or partitions) to a remote server with another array.

The server is running VSphere 5 (in case that matters).  I've seen QNAP storage arrays that will handle mirroring builtin, but I'm not sure about SAS.  Should this service be handled at the VMware level?

What is the right way to solve this problem?

Comment: SAS is a hardware interface and communication protocol. It shouldn't have any bearing on the feature set of whichever storage array you select. Storage mirroring/replication is a function of the feature set of your storage array, not the drive type/interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple solutions available:

- Use a storage device that can replicate. This will be costly, due to the requirement for a fancy box and additional premium feature licenses, but, especially over metro distances, it is well worth it. I have never seen DAS boxes with that capability though, you might have to switch to iscsi/FC/FCoE/NFS/etc
- Use a server that will act as a DAS/NAS/SAN box, and will use a replication technology to another such machine. DRBD and ZFS come to mind. NeverFail on Windows might do the trick, depends what you prefer and know.
- Use VMWare SRM. It pretty much does what you want out of the box, without a SAN or DAS (you can use the local DAS for local VMFS storage though)
- Use a 3rd party solution - Zerto comes to mind, I'm sure there are others.
- Use some sort of replication inside the VMs that really need it. You can use the solutions mentioned in #2

In the end it all comes down to the budget and the RTO/RPO requirements, also, don't just stop at the solutions I mentioned, there are plenty others in the same class as each one of the above.